# Preventing webpage display wrap using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

I have the following page. On page 2, the table is wrapped into a column display on a smartphone. My design requires a side-by-side layout as on a desktop. Is there a way to use a line of Javascript code to override the display wrapping?
Thank you very much!!

This is the link (the table is on page 2 after clicking the button)
https://run.conjoint.ly/study/83578/gu3kh3apu7

**linked script**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://d2n8y5qk0vgut7.cloudfront.net/assets/production/css/../frontend/css/chunk-3cc915f7.02a353df.css?v1.11.10" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://d2n8y5qk0vgut7.cloudfront.net/assets/production/css/bootstrap.min.css?v1.11.10" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://d2n8y5qk0vgut7.cloudfront.net/assets/production/css/respond/common.css?v1.11.10" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://d2n8y5qk0vgut7.cloudfront.net/assets/production/css/zoomjs.css?v1.11.10" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://d2n8y5qk0vgut7.cloudfront.net/assets/production/css/magnify.min.css?v1.11.10" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://d2n8y5qk0vgut7.cloudfront.net/assets/production/css/scales.css?v1.11.10" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://d2n8y5qk0vgut7.cloudfront.net/assets/production/css/../js/addpipe/pipe.css?v1.11.10" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://d2n8y5qk0vgut7.cloudfront.net/assets/production/css/bootstrap-modal-middle.css?v1.11.10" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://d2n8y5qk0vgut7.cloudfront.net/assets/production/css/respond/saas-common.css?v1.11.10" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://d2n8y5qk0vgut7.cloudfront.net/assets/production/css/respond/saastable-template.css?v1.11.10" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://d2n8y5qk0vgut7.cloudfront.net/assets/production/css/froala-v2.9.3/froala_style.min.css?v1.11.10" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://d2n8y5qk0vgut7.cloudfront.net/assets/production/css/froala-v2.9.3/froala_custom.css?v1.11.10" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://d2n8y5qk0vgut7.cloudfront.net/assets/production/js/sha256.min.js?v1.11.10"></script>
<script src="https://d2n8y5qk0vgut7.cloudfront.net/assets/production/js/Sortable.js?v1.11.10"></script>
<script src="https://d2n8y5qk0vgut7.cloudfront.net/assets/production/js/../frontend/js/chunk-a53f42fc.ec1f1878.js?v1.11.10"></script>
<script src="https://d2n8y5qk0vgut7.cloudfront.net/assets/production/js/../frontend/js/chunk-3cc915f7.c840b5ff.js?v1.11.10"></script>
<script src="https://d2n8y5qk0vgut7.cloudfront.net/assets/production/js/../frontend/js/study.4de56ec5.js?v1.11.10"></script>
<script src="https://d2n8y5qk0vgut7.cloudfront.net/assets/production/js/jquery.actual.min.js?v1.11.10"></script>
<script src="https://d2n8y5qk0vgut7.cloudfront.net/assets/production/js/bootstrap-3.3.2.js?v1.11.10"></script>
<script src="https://d2n8y5qk0vgut7.cloudfront.net/assets/production/js/bootstrap-modal.min.js?v1.11.10"></script>
<script src="https://d2n8y5qk0vgut7.cloudfront.net/assets/production/js/jquery.matchHeight.js?v1.11.10"></script>
<script src="https://d2n8y5qk0vgut7.cloudfront.net/assets/production/js/jquery.transit.min.js?v1.11.10"></script>
<script src="https://d2n8y5qk0vgut7.cloudfront.net/assets/production/js/misc.js?v1.11.10"></script>
<script src="https://d2n8y5qk0vgut7.cloudfront.net/assets/production/js/respond/modernizr-custom.js?v1.11.10"></script>
<script src="https://d2n8y5qk0vgut7.cloudfront.net/assets/production/js/hyphenator.js?v1.11.10"></script>
<script src="https://d2n8y5qk0vgut7.cloudfront.net/assets/production/js/remodal.min.js?v1.11.10"></script>
<script src="https://d2n8y5qk0vgut7.cloudfront.net/assets/production/js/polyfill/number-polyfill.js?v1.11.10"></script>
<script src="https://d2n8y5qk0vgut7.cloudfront.net/assets/production/js/respond/common.js?v1.11.10"></script>
<script src="https://d2n8y5qk0vgut7.cloudfront.net/assets/production/js/zoomjs.js?v1.11.10"></script>
<script src="https://d2n8y5qk0vgut7.cloudfront.net/assets/production/js/jquery.magnify.min.js?v1.11.10"></script>
<script src="https://d2n8y5qk0vgut7.cloudfront.net/assets/production/js/detect-browser.js?v1.11.10"></script>
<script src="https://d2n8y5qk0vgut7.cloudfront.net/assets/production/js/js.cookie.min.js?v1.11.10"></script>
<script src="https://d2n8y5qk0vgut7.cloudfront.net/assets/production/js/addpipe/pipe.js?v1.11.10"></script>
<script src="https://d2n8y5qk0vgut7.cloudfront.net/assets/production/js/jquery-ui-1.12.1.custom/jquery-ui.min.js?v1.11.10"></script>
```

The CSS source (common.css) is here:
https://d2n8y5qk0vgut7.cloudfront.net/assets/production/css/respond/common.css?v1.11.10

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

* {
    outline: none !important;
}

h2, h3 {
    margin: 0;
}

body {
    font-size: 18px;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    color: #000;
    background: #fff;
}

h2 {
    font-size: 26px;
}

[disabled="disabled"] {
    pointer-events: none;
}
[disabled="disabled"] img.respond-zoom {
    pointer-events: auto;
}

#progressBar {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;

    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 8px;
    z-index: 101;
}

.full-height {
    height: 100%;
}

.main {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 100%;
}

.frame {
    display: none;
}

.frame img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto !important;
}

.frame .tooltip-inner-custom img {
    max-width: none;
}

.no-scroll {
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 100%;
}

.invisible-scroll .title {
    padding-right: 65px;
}

input[type=radio].conjoint, input[type=checkbox].conjoint {
    display: none;
}

.break-word {
    word-break: break-word;
}

.margin-top-40px {
    margin-top: 40px;
}

.margin-top-20px {
    margin-top: 20px;
}

.margin-bottom-40px {
    margin-bottom: 40px;
}

.margin-bottom-20px {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.iLevelPicture:not([width]) {
    max-height: 150px;
    max-width: 95%;
}

.flex-container {
    height: 100%;

    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    -ms-flex-direction: row;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    -moz-box-align: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    -webkit-box-pack: justify;
    -moz-box-pack: justify;
    -ms-flex-pack: justify;
    -webkit-justify-content: space-between;
    justify-content: space-between;
    -ms-flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

.flex-container > * {
    max-width: 100%;
}

.flex-container-row {
    flex-direction: row;
    -webkit-flex-direction: row;
    -ms-flex-direction: row;
}

.flex-margin {
    margin: auto;
    -ms-flex: 0 0 auto;
}

.flex-2 {
    -webkit-box-flex: 2;
    min-width: 60px;
    flex: 2 1;
    -webkit-flex: 2;
    -ms-flex: 2;
    -moz-box-flex: 2;
}

.flex-1 {
    -webkit-box-flex: 1;
    min-width: 40px;
    flex: 1;
    -webkit-flex: 1;
    -ms-flex: 1;
    -moz-box-flex: 1;
}

.multiple-item {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.multiple-item > input {
    display: none;
}

.multiple-item label {
    white-space: normal;
    font-size: 18px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border: 1px solid rgb(194, 194, 194);
    padding: 10px;
}

.multiple-item label:hover {
    color: grey;
}

.multiple-item .flex-container {
    -ms-flex-align: stretch;
}

.multiple-item input:checked + label,
.btn-vw.iSelected,
.btn-gg.iSelected {
    background: rgb(194, 194, 194) !important;
}

.multiple-other-text {
    background: none;
    border: 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid;
    width: 100%;
}

.table-constantsum {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

.table-constantsum .total {
    font-size: 22px;
}

.table-likert {
    width: 1%;
}

.table-likert-vertically {
    width: 100%;
}

.likert-table-all {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}

.likert-label, .table-constantsum, .scale-label {
    font-size: 18px;
}

.likert-radio:not(.likert-radio-with-text) {
    line-height: 0;
    font-size: 0;
    text-align: center;
}
.likert-radio-text {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.likert-radio .iWrapper {
    width: 75px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.likert-radio label {
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 75px;
    height: 75px;

    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    -ms-flex-pack: center;
    border-radius:5px;
}

.row.visible-md .likert-label-index {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 12px;
    font-size: 18px;
}

.row.visible-sm .likert-label-index {
    position: relative;
    right: -37px;
    font-size: 18px;
}

.table-likert-vertically .likert-radio .iWrapper {
    width: 90px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.table-likert-vertically .likert-radio label {
    width: 90px;
    height: auto;
    min-height: 40px;
}
.table-likert-vertically td.likert-radio {
    padding-bottom: 0;
}
.table-likert-vertically tr:last-child td {
    padding-top: 20px;
}

.table-likert td {
    padding-right: 35px;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}

.table-likert td:last-child {
    padding-right: 0;
}

.table-likert-vertically td {
    text-align: center;
    padding-right: 0;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}

.table-likert-vertically tr:last-child td {
    padding-bottom: 0;
}

.likert-radio label {
    margin: 0;
}

.likert-radio input {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin: 0;
}

.likert-radio label input {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.attribute-names .plan-list .flex-margin {
    margin: auto 0;
    width: 100%;
}

.plan .btn.next-question:active, .plan .btn.next-question-two-stage:active {
    box-shadow: none;
}

.level-label + .level-img, .level-attribute-name + .level-img {
    margin-top: 8px;
}

.help-block {
    color: #DD403A  !important;
    font-size: 14px;
}

.attribute-level-descriptions {
    font-size: 14px;
    white-space: normal;
}

.attribute-level-descriptions a {
    color: #33b774;
}

.attribute-level-descriptions a:hover {
    color: #3ade92;
}

.no-margin *:not(p):not(ul):not(ol) {
    margin: 0;
}

.no-margin > p:first-child {
    margin-top: 0;
}

.no-margin > p:last-child, .no-margin > p.ripple-effect-next {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

.no-padding *:not(ul):not(ol) {
    padding: 0;
}

.max-width * {
    max-width: 100%;
}

iframe {
    max-width: 100%;
}

.alternative-header {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: black;
    padding: 15px 0;
}

@media (max-width: 1199px) {
    .btn-multiple {
        font-size: 16px;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 991px) {
    [class*="col-"] .btn {
        width: 100%;
    }
    [class*="col-"] .frame-additional-question-media-btns .btn{
        width: auto;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
    #frames {
        width: 100%;
    }
    .frame-vw .row .form-group p {
        margin: 0 0 8px 0;
    }
}

.ripple {
    overflow: hidden;
}

.ripple-effect {
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background: white;

    animation: ripple-animation 2s;
}

@keyframes ripple-animation {
    from {
        transform: scale(1);
        opacity: 0.4;
    }
    to {
        transform: scale(100);
        opacity: 0;
    }
}

input[type="number"] {
    text-align: left !important;
}

.number-spin-btn-container {
    display: none !important;
}

.nothing {
    white-space: normal;
}

.break-word {
    word-wrap: break-word;
}

.close {
    font-family: initial;
}

.btn {
    word-break: break-word;
    -ms-word-wrap: break-word;
    white-space: normal;
}

p, ul, ol {
/*    margin: 1em 0; */
}

.tooltip-inner {
    padding: 5px;
}

.tooltip-inner p {
    margin: 3px 0;
}

.btn-gg,
.btn-vw {
    min-width: 200px;
}

.multilingual-choice {
    text-align: center;
    max-width: 400px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.multilingual-choice .btn {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    margin: 10px 0;
}

.tooltip-custom .tooltip-inner-custom {
    display: none;
    text-align: initial;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.tooltip-custom:hover:not(.closed-tooltip) .tooltip-inner-custom {
    display: flex;
    position: fixed !important;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 2000;

    word-break: break-all;
    -ms-hyphens: auto;
    hyphens: auto;
    white-space: normal;
}

.tooltip-inner-custom > button.close {
    top: -5px;
    position: relative;
    margin-left: 10px;
}

.col-xs-5ths,
.col-sm-5ths,
.col-md-5ths,
.col-lg-5ths {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 1px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;
}

.col-xs-5ths {
    width: 20%;
    float: left;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .col-sm-5ths {
        width: 20%;
        float: left;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
    .col-md-5ths {
        width: 20%;
        float: left;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
    .col-lg-5ths {
        width: 20%;
        float: left;
    }
}

.capture-modal-background, .capture-modal {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: 1001;
}

.capture-modal-background {
    background: black;
    opacity: 0.5;
}

.capture-modal {
    z-index: 1002;
}

.capture-modal-content {
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
}

.blur-5px {
    -webkit-transition: all 500ms ;
    -moz-transition: all 500ms ;
    -ms-transition: all 500ms ;
    -o-transition: all 500ms ;
    transition: all 500ms ;

    -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
    -moz-filter: blur(5px);
    -o-filter: blur(5px);
    -ms-filter: blur(5px);
    filter: blur(5px);
}

video, audio {
    max-width: 100%;
}


.likert-radio label:hover {
    background-color: #EAEAEA;
}


.delay {
    opacity: 0.6;
    pointer-events: none;
}

.delay-timer,
.delay-note {
    color: #DD403A;
    font-size: 14px;
    float: right;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

a:link,
a:visited{
    color:#5A4A8E;
    text-decoration: underline;
}

a:hover,
a:active{
    color:#F092DD;
    text-decoration: underline;
}

blockquote{
    font-size: 23px;
    padding: 10px !important;

}

.table-constantsum > hr{
    border:1px;
    border-color: #eee;
    border-style: solid;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

textarea.resize-vertical-only {
    resize: vertical;
}
.video-js .vjs-big-play-button{
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}

button.pulse-button {
    cursor: pointer;
    animation: borderPulse 1000ms infinite ease-out;
}

button.pulse-button:hover,
button.pulse-button:focus {
    animation: borderPulse 1000ms infinite ease-out, hoverShine 200ms;
}
.file-preview .fileinput-remove{
    display:none;
}
/* Declare border pulse animation */
@keyframes borderPulse {
    0% {
        box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 10px rgba(226, 132, 132,.1), 0px 0px 0px 0px rgba(226, 132, 132,.2);
    }
    100% {
        box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 5px rgba(226, 132, 132,.2), 0px 0px 0px 10px rgba(255,255,255,0);
    }
}

/* Declare shine on hover animation */
@keyframes hoverShine {
    0%{
        background-image: linear-gradient(135deg, rgba(0,255,255,.4) 0%, rgba(0,255,255,0) 50%, rgba(0,255,255,0) 100%);
    }
    50%{
        background-image: linear-gradient(135deg, rgba(0,255,255,0) 0%, rgba(0,255,255,.4) 50%, rgba(0,255,255,0) 100%);
    }
    100%{
        background-image: linear-gradient(135deg, rgba(0,255,255,0) 0%, rgba(0,255,255,0) 50%, rgba(0,255,255,.4) 100%);
    }
}

.preview-notifier {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 21px;
    line-height: 1;
    padding: 1em;
    background: white;
    box-shadow: 0 8px 16px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    cursor: move;
    z-index: 10000;
}

.preview-notifier-close {
    margin-left: 1.5em;
}

.js-disable-parent-flex-behaviour {
    text-align: left;
}

img.fr-dib:not(.respond-zoom):not(.magnify-zoom) {
    pointer-events: none;
}

.modal-header,
.modal-footer {
    border: 0;
}

.modal-footer .btn,
.modal-footer .btn + .btn {
    margin: 2px;
}
```

Comment: Please put the code here, not at external sites.

Comment: The solution is probably to use media queries in your CSS to specify appropriate layout on small devices.

Comment: Am I correct in assuming that it's not your webpage, and you are unable to edit global CSS styles here, hence asking for JS solution? If that's not the case, and you can actually edit CSS, then it's a simple matter of adjusting media queries.

Comment: You are right. I do not have control over the CSS, hence the JS solution.